# What part of wattage am I not understanding?

Tags: power, audio, dc, watts

I was looking on the bottom of an electronic product and I noticed it stated these two things:

Input: 5V 2A Audio output: 15 W

I was taught V x A = Watts

How is this device taking what I assume is 10 watts of input and generating 15 watts of output?

Comment: You understand correctly. Unless it has a battery or other internal power source, I believe it could be an typo/error. It should say 10W, assuming VA is correct. The best way to test this is to measure how much current and voltage the device is actually drawing by using a multimeter.

Comment: Generally speaking, most suppliers of audio equipment try to befuddle the user with outlandish claims of audio power output that upon deeper investigation lead to the fact that the supplier is quoting something like "peak music power" (equals twice regular or average power).

Comment: The audio output might be peak output watts for some short period of time. We don't know what device you have, what are the specs for it, and how it works.

Comment: The audio equipment industry is notorious for various kinds of rubbish definitions of power of amplifiers, speakers etc.  For a survey of what nonsense people have seen, have a look at this article about [audio power ratings](https://www.audioholics.com/audio-amplifier/amplifier-power-ratings)

Comment: I appreciate all these comments. I will admit a simple capacitor totally slipped my mind because I was thinking continuous power not peak power. I appreciate the reminder all have given.

Comment: I have a "200W" computer speaker powered by a 9V 200mA adapter. I have little reason to doubt the 9V @200mA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you don't understand is probably the audio equipment marketspeak.

The device may have an internal energy storage (a battery or at least a big-big capacitor) so in theory it may be capable for putting out 15W for some period of time. If the energy storage is capable (a battery), the period may as well be few hours. Capacitors are usually good for a second or half.

For a general-purpose audio devices, this is okay-ish because most music and speech have a large difference between the peak power and the average power (e.g. 20x-50x for speech or a beat-intensive music).

On the other hand, if you feed a single constant tone to the device, its many-watts claim will die a horrible death.

Audio device manufacturers tend to boast either the maximum power the device is capable for an arbitrary short period of time, or a completely made-up number which in their understanding represents some aspect of the device usefulness.

Comment: Ah, yes, a big-ass capacitor.

Comment: Essentially, serious listings are in RMS.  "Music power" tends to be inflated by a factor of at least 2, and "PMPO" (peak music power output or something) by a factor of 100 or more and does not really have any connection with actual power but is more like a model number for puny speakers.  Even a big renowned Japanese music hardware manufacturers sells amps with output power specs exceeding mains power wattage requirements, an obvious exaggeration.

Comment: @user107063 No, power is *never* given in RMS. If something claims some kind of "RMS power", look for something else--RMS is *completely meaningless* when it comes to power.

Comment: @Hearth My Peavey amps have RMS ratings on their back and they correspond reasonably closely to what the power rails will deliver on a sine signal at the nominal speaker impedance.  This is not a full measure of available loudness since speaker efficiency factors into that as well.  At the same time, it's definitely more useful information than what Roland advertises for its amps (the bigger the amp, the more the "rated" power exceeds the mains power draw).  As an example, a Peavey KB300 has label "130 Watts, 23V RMS, 4 Ohms minimum speaker load" and a mains power rating of 400W.

Comment: @user107063 *volts* RMS is perfectly sensible and expected. As is RMS current. But I'm saying that the audio equipment you see out there that makes claims about *watts* RMS is utter nonsense and should never be trusted.

Comment: @Hearth, Re, "watts RMS is utter nonsense." Maybe it provides no actionable information when it appears in the spec sheet of an audio amplifier—maybe it's even a completely bogus, made-up number in some spec sheets; but for whatever it's worth, the RMS value of any time-varying quantity is [well defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Definition).

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well-defined doesn't mean it's in any way useful. And the numbers paired with it on audio equipment ads are usually completely unrelated to anything resembling the item in the box.

Comment: Actually, a real power specification is mostly useless since speaker impedances are complex and frequency-dependent.  Since solid-state amps are designed as voltage followers, their ratings are given for driving resistive loads instead of speakers, leading to an RMS rating for continuous power delivery.

Comment: @Hearth, Yes. I agree. But the newbie asking the question deserves to know the difference between a concept that is meaningless or useless _in some context,_ and a concept that is so completely and utterly ill-defined that it has no physical meaning.

Comment: @user107063 while speakers have their share of complex properties, their impedance generally behaves well within 15% of their DC resistance over their rated frequency range. Compared to the wild numbers in the amp specs, this can be forgiven wholeheartedly. And if you don't like the simple voltage-source-like solid state amplifiers, you can always try the real hardcore - the class-A thermionic valve last stage with an output transformer. Impedance match THIS!

Comment: @Hearth take it up with the standards people. DIN 45324 and IEC60268 use output power with a pink noise input of defined shape, and "power of a x volts RMS signal" somehow got shortened to RMS power in the process.